# neighbor div in a navigation bar is affected by increasing font-size in a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a navigation using bootstrap and css.
Here is the below code, The error here is font size of one div is affecting neighbor div's

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row menubar">

        <div class="col-md-12 menu" >
            <div class="webbrand"><span>KA</span><span>RA</span></div>
            <div class="courses">hemanth</div>
            <div class="courses">hemanth</div>
        </div>  
    </div> 
</div>
```

**Below is the css**

```
menu{
height: 60px;
}
.webbrand{
    font-family: "Gotham SSm A", "Gotham SSm B", sans-serif;
    font-size: 200%;
    padding: 0px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    color:white;
    height: 100%;

}
.courses{
    font-family: "Gotham SSm A", "Gotham SSm B", sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:1%;
    margin-right:1%;
    color:white;
    height: 100%;

}
.menubar{
    background:#1e1e1e;
    height: 60px;
    align-items: center;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the error you're referring to? The example does what it should do, so it might be a misunderstanding about how it's supposed to behave.

Comment: Can you just specify once, what is expected? Because I can see for the first `webbrand` you have added font as 200% and for rest 100 %. So do you want to make the KARA is bigger than the other option? or do you want it to adjustment vertically middle?

Comment: Yes I want "KARA" to be bigger in size and align them vertically center of nav bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is this:

```
.menu{
    height: 60px;
}
```

and this:

```
.courses{
    ....

    height: 100%; // This is your culprit, try remove this line.

}
```

By setting your `courses` element's height to 100%, you are setting it to 60px since it is the child of `menu` element. (`menu` element's height is 60px)

Remove the `height: 100%` in the `.courses` and I think your problem would be solved.

**EDIT**

Based on the comments, try using this:

```
.webbrand{
    ....
    float: left;
    line-height: 60px;
}
.courses{
    ....
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 60px;
}
```

See snippet for the working code.

```css
.menu{
    height: 60px;
}
.webbrand{
    font-family: "Gotham SSm A", "Gotham SSm B", sans-serif;
    font-size: 200%;
    padding: 0px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    color:white;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    line-height: 60px;
}
.webbrand:hover{
    background: red;
}
.courses{
    font-family: "Gotham SSm A", "Gotham SSm B", sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:1%;
    margin-right:1%;
    color:white;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 60px;
}
.courses:hover{
    background-color: red;
}
.menubar{
    background:#1e1e1e;
    height: 60px;
    align-items: center;
    line-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row menubar">

        <div class="col-md-12 menu" >
            <div class="webbrand"><span>KA</span><span>RA</span></div>
            <div class="courses">hemanth</div>
            <div class="courses">hemanth</div>
        </div>  
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: How can you tell that the OP's problem is the 60px height of `.courses`?

Comment: @MrLister Based on OP's screenshot, I assume OP doesn't want the element in the "hermanth" div has height exceeding the bar

Comment: I wanted it to be 100% because when I hover on it background color should change on that entire div

Comment: @YashwanthPotu Then the problem is that the divs are in different vertical locations? That's caused by the vertical alignment. Set it to `top` or `bottom`, or basically anything except the default `baseline`.

Comment: @MrLister I've added his code in the snippet, just in case you want to play with the working code and put it in your answer :)

Comment: jsfiddle.net/bekkqsd5 ,  I changed the code a little and updated in jfiddle,Please hover on each element and see the error you will understand what I am @MrLister

Comment: @YashwanthPotu I've edited my answer based on your requirement in these comments :) , I've also edited the snippet

Comment: @YashwanthPotu added the hover feature in my snippet based on your jsfiddle

Comment: If I remove remove the float:left in your code the hover functionality does not work properly, but I didn't understand how float is helping here @samAlvin, Can you explain this

Comment: @YashwanthPotu Notice the `display:inline-block;` in `.courses` and `.webbrand`, the `float:left` enables the `.courses` and `.webbrand` to be inlined. If you remove the `float:left`, then the divs would appear below the previous div, not beside the previous div.

Comment: If I remove remove the float:left in your code the hover functionality does not work properly, but I didn't understand how float is helping here @samAlvin, Can you explain that

Comment: @YashwanthPotu this is the description of `float` from MDN, "The float CSS property specifies that an element should be placed along the left or right side of its container, allowing text and inline elements to wrap around it." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float